# How to reduce Apache's HttpClient jar size

Tags: apache, maven, jar, size, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache's httpclient-4.1.3 which is 352.6 KB. Is there any way to decrease the size of that jar file?

P.S. I am using Maven to manage jar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to exclude unused dependencies using maven exclude. For more information see [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).